# Compare arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, comparison

I'm having some issues comparing two arrays:

```
int array[3] = {23, 14, 1};

if (array == {12, 43, 1}) {
    // Do something
}
```

The error I get is:

```
error: expected primary-expression before '{' token

       if (array == {12, 43, 1}) {

                        ^

error: expected ')' before '{' token
```

I also tried this:

```
bool compareArrays(int firstArray[], int secondArray[], int length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (firstArray[i] != secondArray[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

But I get another error when I do so:

```
if (compareArrays(array, {12, 43, 1}, 3)) {
    // Do something
}

error: cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'int*' for argument '2' to 'bool compareArrays(int*, int*, int)'
```

How can I solve the problem ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use `std::array<int,3>` and compare directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This declaration:

```
bool compareArrays(int firstArray[], int secondArray[], int length) {
```

accepts pointers to `int`s. But you can't decay a brace-init list to a pointer.

Instead, the function can accept fixed-size arrays, and compare them with an algorithm:

```
template<size_t N>
bool compareArrays(int (&firstArray)[N], int (&secondArray)[N]) {
  return std::equal(std::begin(firstArray),std::end(firstArray),
                    std::begin(secondArray));
}
```

Note that you no longer need to pass `length` as the function will deduce it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::array`. With C++20 it's as simple as

```
#include <array>

int main() {
    int array[3] = {23, 14, 1};

    if (std::to_array(array) == std::array{12, 43, 1}) {
    // Do something
    }
}
```

Or with C++17

```
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array array = {23, 14, 1};

    if (array == std::array{12, 43, 1}) {
    // Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another suggestion. You can use [std::memcmp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcmp) to compare arrays whose elements are ints or other PODs.